# why printf("%d", getchar()) printing an extra 10

Tags: c, printf, getchar

In the program, `printf("%d", getchar())` is printing an extra 10.

when i give input like a, it prints 9710 instead of 97, same for others

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int c;
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        printf("%d", c);
    }
    printf("\n\tENDED\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

```
me@Device-xx:~/Desktop/Test/Tmps$ gcc 118.c -o 118
me@Device-xx:~/Desktop/Test/Tmps$ ./118
a
9710s
11510x
12010
```

Comment: What keys did you press, (note the plural)?

Comment: 10 - ASCII LF - line feed - newline. It's not an "extra" 10 but what you typed.

Comment: look up UTF8 code 10, this might give you a clue.

Comment: Please markdown you code the right way. Thank you!

Comment: Decimal 97 is `'a'`, and decimal 10 is the newline character.  Exactly what you typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't pass `a` to STDIN. Because you pressed `a` and Enter, you passed `a` and a Line Feed. Assuming an ASCII-based encoding (such as UTF-8),

1. The letter `a` is encoded as 0x61 = 97
2. A Line Feed is encoded as 0x0A = 10

Maybe you want

```
while (1) {
    int c = getchar();
    // Stop when a Line Feed or EOF is encountered.
    if (c == EOF || c == 0x0A) {
         break;
    }

    printf("%d", c);
}
```